# How can I access a class component method in a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, filepond

I'm trying to access a class component method inside a function component. I have been reading for hours but I'm missing something.

To be precise, I'm trying to access a method (addFiles) of the Filepond component (https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/)

As readed in the documentation, I can ref the class component:

```
<FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref}/>
```

And then I can use the method like this:

```
this.pond.addFiles();
```

But I can't use that method in my Function because 'this' can't be used in a Function.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'pond' of undefined

I though useRef hook could help, but it only works in html elements.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FilePond } from "react-filepond";

const Example = () => {

   //How can I use this.pond.addFiles() here?

   return(
      <FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref} />
   )
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the functional component related to the class component? Ie grandparent/parent/child?

Comment: Why don't you just convert your functional component into a class component, hence, it resembles the behavior described in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UseRef will create a ref. The useRef Hook is a function that returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

```
const refContainer = useRef(initialValue);
```

You can use this code

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { FilePond } from "react-filepond";

const Example = () => {
  const file = useRef(null);

   // Use file.current.addFiles() instead of this.pond.addFiles();

   return(
      <FilePond ref={file} />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't work with useRef that often but I think it should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FilePond } from "react-filepond";

const Example = () => {
   const filePondRef = useRef(null);
   // you should be able to use filePondRef (filePondRef.current) instead of "this.pond"

   return(
      <FilePond ref={filePondRef} />
   )
}
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: ¡Thank you so much, it works! I forgot to include .current. Thank you Tim for solving my problem so fast!